# Why is my Stack Exchange code formatting considered wrong?

Tags: bug, status-declined, stack-exchange, code-formatting

I want to ask a question on Stack Overflow, but it keeps telling:

> Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because:
>
> Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.

I have checked in the editor that all my code is nicely indented with 4 spaces and I have no idea how to ask that question now.

Here is the question that wont show in SO :

```
I would like to know if there is any way of getting the activity result some other way than in the onActivityResult() method.

I have written a sample of what I would like to achieve. Button 1 and 2 Is how a normal android app would handle some activity result, and **is it possible to make button 3 from this example to work?** 

This ConfirmActivity class would be called from lots of different places in the code, and handling all those calls in a single function would be really ugly. Getting a result like I showed with button 3 would make the code really clean. I really don't care how much work it goes to making that happen cause once it's done I can just hide that and be happy. I have been thinking of creating threads that would wait for that activity to end and continue work later, or something like that, but I haven't been able to find any way I could make that work. 
If this can be done with a dialog it would be nice as well, I just used an activity here for the example to make it more clear.


Here is the whole code (sorry, if try to explain it with a few line, it seems just to confuse people)

        
    package com.stack.overflow;
    
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.LinearLayout;
    
    public class StackquestionActivity extends Activity {
        private static final int CONFIRM_ACTIVIY = 0;
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            LinearLayout l = new LinearLayout(this);
            Button b1 = new Button(this), b2 = new Button(this), b3 = new Button(this);
            b1.setText("do thing 1");
            b2.setText("something");
            b3.setText("else");
            l.addView(b1);
            l.addView(b2);
            l.addView(b3);
            b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    showConfirmActivity(1);
                }
            });
            b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    showConfirmActivity(2);
                }
            });
            b3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    if (showConfirmActivity(3) == 1){ // i would like to continue here after the confirm activity ends
                        //give user what he wants
                    }else {
                        //say you are sorry and send him away
                    }
                }
            });
            setContentView(l);
        }
        private int showConfirmActivity(int act){
            Intent i = new Intent(this, ConfirmActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("request_id", act);
            startActivityForResult(i, CONFIRM_ACTIVIY);
            return 0; // this is where i would like to have a result from the called activity
        }
        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == CONFIRM_ACTIVIY) {
                int request_id = data.getIntExtra("request_id", 0);
                int ok = data.getIntExtra("ok", 0);
                String response = data.getStringExtra("response");
                Log.v("onActivityResult", "request_id = "+request_id);
                Log.v("onActivityResult", " ok        = "+ok );
                Log.v("onActivityResult", " response  = "+response);
                switch (request_id) {
                    case 1: Log.v("onActivityResult", "continue code from button 1");
                        if (ok==1){
                            //give user what he wants
                        }else {
                            //say you are sorry and send him away
                        }
                        break;
                    case 2: Log.v("onActivityResult", "continue code from button 2");
                        if (ok==1){
                            //give user what he wants
                        }else {
                            //say you are sorry and send him away
                        }
                        break;
                    case 3: Log.v("onActivityResult", "continue code from button 3");
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }



ConfirmActivity would be some activity (like a popup or a dialog), for user to interact with confirm a few things. 


here is a rar of the working example  
<http://dl.dropbox.com/u/722768/stackquestion.rar>  
and the individual files  
<http://dl.dropbox.com/u/722768/AndroidManifest.xml>  
<http://dl.dropbox.com/u/722768/StackquestionActivity.java>  
<http://dl.dropbox.com/u/722768/ConfirmActivity.java>
```

Thank you for any pointers, and I know that is a lot of code to put there, but I believe it's for a good reason.

Comment: I read this question optimistically hoping that we now warned users upon submission of links to dropbox... Bummer

Comment: Off topic, but this is a LOT of code to be posting for one question, not even counting the 4 extra files you posted. People don't want to read through mountains of source and pick through external files just to answer your question. Consider narrowing the question and posting just a few lines of code! Also, links to external files are usually okay, but don't expect people to bother reading through them unless they're *really* curious about your project.

Comment: Confirmed. This is a bug in the Stack Exchange filter.
The bug has been fixed at Stack Overflow, but not at
[Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/ask),
where anyone can still reproduce the bug.
Just press *Review your question* (with your Markdown of course),
and you'll see the error.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This bit:

```
<http://dl.dropbox.com/u/722768/stackquestion.rar>  
and the individual files  
<http://dl.dropbox.com/u/722768/AndroidManifest.xml>  
<http://dl.dropbox.com/u/722768/StackquestionActivity.java>  
<http://dl.dropbox.com/u/722768/ConfirmActivity.java>
```

... is tripping the code warning.

---

1. Using an unregistered account, I attempted to open a question with the OP's code.  I got these errors:

   > Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because:
   >
   > - Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as
   >     code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button
   >     or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?]
   >     toolbar icon.
   > - we're sorry, but as a spam prevention mechanism, new users can only
   >     post a maximum of two hyperlinks. Earn more than 10 reputation to post
   >     more hyperlinks.
   > - Email does not appear to be valid

   (Note that I used a deliberately bogus email to avoid accidentally creating a question.)
2. Indenting this block, with the ***Code*** button:

   ```
   <http://dl.dropbox.com/u/722768/stackquestion.rar>  
   and the individual files  
   <http://dl.dropbox.com/u/722768/AndroidManifest.xml>  
   <http://dl.dropbox.com/u/722768/StackquestionActivity.java>  
   <http://dl.dropbox.com/u/722768/ConfirmActivity.java>
   ```

   I got:

   > Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because:
   >
   > - Email does not appear to be valid
3. Unindenting the block again yields, again:

   > Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because:
   >
   > - Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as
   >     code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button
   >     or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?]
   >     toolbar icon.
   > - we're sorry, but as a spam prevention mechanism, new users can only
   >     post a maximum of two hyperlinks. Earn more than 10 reputation to post
   >     more hyperlinks.
   > - Email does not appear to be valid

---

Even though that block contains [valid URL markdown](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#bare-urls), perhaps so many of them, in a block formation, is fooling the code sniffer into treating it as HTML?

Comment: Its not malformed, I actually tried both and it even says _In most cases, a plain URL will be recognized as such and automatically linked: Visit http://area51.stackexchange.com/ regularly!
Use angle brackets to force linking: Have you seen <http://superuser.com>?_

Comment: The problem aside: I really dislike questions that link to some Dropbox account. @zid, please remember we're Q&A sites not some help forums, so now we expect you to keep the linked files available **forever**!

Comment: @Arjan, sorry, When I posted the question I thought that it wouldn't work here as well. But it seems to be a problem just with SO, so I removed the link and put the code here to be available with this post. I will be careful not to do that again, but the links in the code will remain cause that is how i wanted to post it.

Comment: The problem is not with the brackets placed before and after the link, because that is the syntax that is reported valid in the help.

Comment: The help button that appears in the text field where you write an answer reports this text, when you click on "Links": `Use angle brackets to force linking: Have you seen <http://superuser.com>`. It is also what appears in the [how to format](http://i.stack.imgur.com/lKm4Z.png) block.

Comment: @Brock Adams both the "how to format" block and the help for the "Your Answer" field reports that `<http://example.com>` is correct syntax. I have never used it, but I guess that in some cases it could help.

Comment: @Brock Adams The link you reported links to a page that shows `<http://example.com>` can be used. Under "Bare URLs," I read: "Force URLs by enclosing them in angle brackets: `Have you seen <http://example.com>?`" See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#bare-urls.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: So it does.  Must be getting tired; skimmed right over that part.

Comment: @Brock Adams I must admit it is not in the place one would expect it to be, and I remember that part just because I saw it in the "how to format" block. As far as I recall, that block is now only visible to who asks a question; that means that if you normally answer to questions, you could see that block less frequently.

Comment: Well it would seem it's not the whole block, cause I posted comments like that before, and **the one that is causing the problems is the .xml file**! Thank you guys for helping, but what should I do now. I think this is a weird bug that needs to be fixed.

Comment: Well, this question is now a bug report, one of the devs should get around to it eventually (usually). I don't know if it helps to keep the question unanswered or not.

Comment: I don't think this is possible to disambiguate from un-code-formatted-XML reliably, and even if it was, it's a total edge case that had other problems. So it's [status-wontfix].. but excellent detective work!