# Can't post question due to code formatting checker

Tags: support, markdown, indentation

I've tried indenting everything, except for syntax highlighting which I was going to edit after my post it's "blocking" the code correctly, but the code formatting checker keeps rejecting it. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Apparently I've seen I can post it here.  Maybe someone knows what's wrong?  I've even indented stuff that's not code, but rather terminal commands, just to be safe:

I'm having one hell of a time with SWIG, due in part to the lack of good C++ examples to learn from. I finally got my first program to compile with SWIG, but am having troubles running it. Let me just get right to the code...

setup.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

"""
setup.py file for SWIG example
"""

from distutils.core import setup, Extension


decklist_module = Extension('_decklist',
                           sources=['decklist_wrap.cxx', 'decklist.cpp'],
                           )

setup (name = 'decklist',
       version = '0.1',
       author      = "Me",
       description = """Testing!""",
       ext_modules = [decklist_module],
       py_modules = ["decklist"],
       )
```

decklist.hpp:

```
#include <boost/unordered_map.hpp>



class DeckList{
private:
        boost::unordered_map<std::string, int> mainBoard;
        boost::unordered_map<std::string, int> sideBoard;
    public:
        void addCard(std::string name, int cardCount);
        int getCount(std::string cardName);
        DeckList();
        ~DeckList();

};
decklist.cpp: #ifndef DECKLIST_H #define DECKLIST_H #include "decklist.hpp" #include

DeckList::DeckList(){

}

void DeckList::addCard(std::string cardName, int cardCount){
    mainBoard[cardName] = cardCount;
}

int DeckList::getCount(std::string cardName){
    return mainBoard[cardName];
}

#endif
```

decklist.i:

```
//decklist.i
%module decklist
%{
    #include "decklist.hpp"
%}
#include "decklist.hpp"
```

Now on the terminal (I am on Ubuntu Natty Narwhal), I run the following two commands:

```
swig -python -c++ decklist.i
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

The second gives me the following response:

```
running build_ext
building '_decklist' extension
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c decklist_wrap.cxx -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/decklist_wrap.o
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wstrict-prototypes" is valid for Ada/C/ObjC but not for C++
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c decklist.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/decklist.o
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wstrict-prototypes" is valid for Ada/C/ObjC but not for C++
g++ -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/decklist_wrap.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/decklist.o -o /home/aespiel1/deck/_decklist.so
```

But I wind up with: 
decklist.cpp 
decklist.hpp 
decklist.i 
decklist.py 
decklist.pyc 
_decklist.so 
decklist_wrap.cxx 
setup.py 
and a build folder with .o files for both the decklist_wrap and decklist files.

If I run python in idle and switch into this directory and import:

```
import decklist
```

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "", line 1, in import decklist ImportError: No module named decklist
```

Strangely, if I run it from the terminal, I can import decklist. But then a command like:

```
dl = decklist.DeckList()
```

gives:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "", line 1, in AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'DeckList'
```

What am I doing wrong? I am so frustrated.

Comment: It exists because too many posts were posted without formatting for the code, which caused unreadable code. It's pretty new, so maybe it will be improved over time but it does help keep the site cleaner and with better looking code - thousands of people do post code, every hour.

Comment: @Siva - that's not relevant - the new feature won't let him post it that's the whole problem here.

Comment: Can you add the code to this post so that we can take a look at it?

Comment: Posting a screenshot of the question that's being rejected would make it possible for someone to help you

Comment: The code formatting checker is a relatively new feature, you're posting a fair amount of code, and Python-SWIG questions are fairly rare so I'm guessing you have indeed found a bug. Looks like a fun one for the devs to figure out.

Comment: possible duplicate of [I can't post my question because of the "indentation"! How do I fix this?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99733/i-cant-post-my-question-because-of-the-indentation-how-do-i-fix-this)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is my Stack Exchange code formatting considered wrong?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100369/why-is-my-stack-exchange-code-formatting-considered-wrong)

Comment: I tried the things in those discussions and nothing helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my own problem.

It turns out the checker saw my list of files in my directory and thought it was code.

This is clearly a bug; those are not code and should not need to be treated as such.  Or if they should be treated by such, that should be documented in the help.

How can this be forwarded to the stackoverflow support center?

Btw, thanks for the helpful replies.

Comment: A list of files needs to be formatted *somehow*. Either as code or as a bulleted list. There's no bug here; possibly the error message could be made more clear, but the point still gets across that there's a formatting problem with your post.

Comment: The error message HAS to be made more clear.  It is NOWHERE in the help, and a file list is NOT code.

Answer (score 5):

Check out this question:
[Why is my Stack Exchange code formatting considered wrong?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100369/why-is-my-stack-exchange-code-formatting-considered-wrong)

If no luck, try changing your browser font size according [to this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99733/i-cant-post-my-question-because-of-the-indentation-how-do-i-fix-this) it might also help.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99733/i-cant-post-my-question-because-of-the-indentation-how-do-i-fix-this was that other question you were thinking of.

Comment: Thanks for finding it, edited the answer now.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but neither of those worked.  I've already tried indenting; as you can see, there is nothing in my post that looks like code that hasn't been formatted to look like code.  Changing my browser's font size did nothing.